# Having some trouble in inserting data into a Postgresql table

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert some data into a table but couldn't able to do this. The Error, I am getting is this - "Syntax error at or near insert".

The table that I have created -

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
       (EMPNO integer NOT NULL,
        ENAME VARCHAR(10),
        JOB VARCHAR(9),
        MGR integer,
        HIREDATE DATE,
        SAL integer,
        COMM integer,
        DEPTNO integer)
```

The Data that I am trying to insert -

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7369, 'SMITH',  'CLERK',     7902,
        '1980-12-17',  800, NULL, 20)
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7499, 'ALLEN',  'SALESMAN',  7698,
        '1981-2-20', 1600,  300, 30)
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7521, 'WARD',   'SALESMAN',  7698,
        '1981-2-22', 1250,  500, 30)
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7566, 'JONES',  'MANAGER',   7839,
        '1981-4-2',  2975, NULL, 20)
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN',  7698,
        '1981-9-28', 1250, 1400, 30)
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7698, 'BLAKE',  'MANAGER',   7839,
        '1981-5-1',  2850, NULL, 30)
```

The Error is happening in the second Insert Statement or the 4th line of the code.

Comment: Aren't you missing `;` after every `INSERT`?

Comment: I inserted all of them and did not have any problem as you can see [here](https://gyazo.com/8d0231c0e4ab1840a356c553a3fddba0). Remember to add `;`and the end of every query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to revise your scripts as like as this.

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7369, 'SMITH',  'CLERK',     7902,
        '1980-12-17',  800, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7499, 'ALLEN',  'SALESMAN',  7698,
        '1981-2-20', 1600,  300, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7521, 'WARD',   'SALESMAN',  7698,
        '1981-2-22', 1250,  500, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7566, 'JONES',  'MANAGER',   7839,
        '1981-4-2',  2975, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN',  7698,
        '1981-9-28', 1250, 1400, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7698, 'BLAKE',  'MANAGER',   7839,
        '1981-5-1',  2850, NULL, 30);
```

Or, like this.

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK',7902,'1980-12-17',  800, NULL, 20),
(7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN',7698,'1981-2-20', 1600,  300, 30),
(7521, 'WARD', 'SALESMAN', 7698,'1981-2-22', 1250,  500, 30),
(7566, 'JONES','MANAGER', 7839,'1981-4-2',  2975, NULL, 20),
(7654, 'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,'1981-9-28', 1250, 1400, 30),
(7698, 'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,'1981-5-1',  2850, NULL, 30);
```

Personally, I prefer the last one.

Comment: Thanks, Everyone for the help. I am new to SQL so didn't know too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
            (7369, 'SMITH',  'CLERK',7902,'1980-12-17',  800, NULL, 20),
            (7499, 'ALLEN',  'SALESMAN',7698,'1981-2-20', 1600,  300, 30),
            (7521, 'WARD',   'SALESMAN',7698,'1981-2-22', 1250,  500, 30),
            (7566, 'JONES',  'MANAGER', 7839,'1981-4-2',  2975, NULL, 20),
            (7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN',7698,'1981-9-28', 1250, 1400, 30),
            (7698, 'BLAKE',  'MANAGER',7839,'1981-5-1',  2850, NULL, 30)
```